# Match comma separated groups in regexp (without redundancy in pattern)

Tags: .net, regex

I have a regexp that matches strings that represent Excel ranges (plus single cells)

```
^[A-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*(:[A-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*)?(,[A-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*(:[A-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*)?)*$
```

It matches, for example, strings like:

```
C5:H6,J5:P6,R5:DM6,C15
```

I'm asking if there is any way to avoid the redundancy in the pattern:

`C6` is matched by `[A-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*` but also `H6` is matched by the same pattern.

Similarly `J6:P6` is matched by the same pattern that matches `C6:H6`.

If want to express something like *"match this pattern 1 time, or * times but only if comma separated"*.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would be nice if you can show us examples of what should and what should not be matched...

Comment: It should match `C5:H6,J5:P6,R5:DM6,C15` but not `C5:H6,J5:P6,R5:DM6,C15,`, not `,C5:H6,J5:P6,R5:DM6,C15`, not `C5:H6,J5:P6:R6,R5:DM6,C15` and etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the regex as follows:

```
^([A-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*(:[A-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*)?(,(?!$)|$))*$
```

The key change is this sub-expression at the end:

```
(,(?!$)|$)
```

It matches an optional comma character except when it is at the end of the match, in which case there must be no further characters. This prevents you from matching a sequence that ends in a hanging comma.

Here is the corresponding [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/VuKrGQ).

Comment: I found out that your regex also matches some non-well-formatted strings like `C5:H6J5:P6,R5:DM6,C15` as you can see http://ideone.com/gSWfbH.

Comment: I edited your sub-expression at the end as follows `(,(?!$)|(?=$))` and it seems to work fine. It matches a comma not followed by end-of-string OR nothing followed by end-of-string. Do you see any error in it?

Comment: Finally modified the regex to also avoid redundancy in range detection, it should work but please give a look: `^(([A-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*((?=,|$)|:(?!(,|$)))){1,2}(,(?!$)|(?=$)))*$`

Comment: @Teejay You are right, the possibility of empty match instead of a comma produced some unexpected results. I replaced `(?=$)` with a simple `$`, it has the same effect and a zero-width. Your second expression is shorter, but it is a lot harder to understand. I would go with the fixed-up expression that has only one look-ahead, because it is much easier to read.

Comment: As I asked before on @RayToal answer, would it be more correct to write `(,(?!$)|(?=$))` instead of your `(,(?!$)|$)`? Pratically they seems to act same, but theoretically mine should be better since `$` is already eat by the dollar at the end. Please let me know if I'm right.

Comment: @Teejay There's no difference, because `$` is a *zero-width* anchor, so it does not consume any input. In other words, it matches a position, rather than a character, so your expression can "eat" it multiple times. Normally, you wrap an expression in `(?=<something>)` to prevent it from consuming input; the `$` does not consume any input anyway, so wrapping it in a look-ahead is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

To remove redundancy in your source code, you could store the repeated components into string variables and construct the regex out of a string.

Something like this:

```
string cellname = "[A-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*";
string cellrange = cellname + "(:" + cellname + ")?";
Regex pattern = new Regex("^" + cellrange + "(," + cellrange + ")*$")
```

If you are asking whether there is a binary regex operator for separators, i.e., something for which you could write

```
A op B
```

and have it mean

```
A(BA)*
```

then I'm afraid such a thing does not exist.  **ADDENDUM**: However, you can get close with

```
((^|B)A)+$
```

This translates into "one or more As prefixed by either the beginning of the string or a B."  Here your B will be the comma and your As will be ranges.  You can then use the same technique inside the ranges to get cells separated with colons.  But instead of `(^|,)` you will use `(xxx|:)` where `xxx` plays the role of beginning of the cell.  I'm not sure what that would be.  Can you work with that?

**ADDENDUM 2**

Solution at http://ideone.com/L3RNEr  -- based on my last comment.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Regex rx = new Regex("^([A-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*(:[A-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*)?($|,(?!$)))*$");
        Console.WriteLine(rx.IsMatch("C5:H6"));
        Console.WriteLine(rx.IsMatch("C5"));
        Console.WriteLine(rx.IsMatch("C5:H6,J5:P6,R5:DM6,C15"));
        Console.WriteLine(rx.IsMatch("C5:H6,J5:P6,R5:DM6,C15,"));
        Console.WriteLine(rx.IsMatch("C5:H6J5:P6,R5:DM6,C15"));
        Console.WriteLine(rx.IsMatch(",C5:H6:J5:P6,R5:DM6,C15"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm actually looking for a more polished solution, not code-based, but regex-based, if it exists.

Comment: You'll be able to improve on what you have using lookaround (as other answers show) but even so you'll have to repeat the `[A-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*` part.  Disclaimer: I don't have a formal proof of this. :)  I'll add something to my answer though.

Comment: Thanks for your addendum. The solution shown in it is the one I love the most. Unfortunately it seems to also match comma-beginning strings. Similarly, if I put `(,|$)` at the end, it also matches comma-ending strings. Any idea to avoid this?

Comment: To avoid matching comma-beginning strings, you begin with "The beginning of the string OR a comma-not-preceded-by-the-beginning" i.e. `(^|,(?<!^)`.  Or at the end, say "The end OR a comma-not-followed-by-the-end", i.e. `($|$(?!$))`.  HTH!

Comment: Added ideone link to answer.  Also upvoted your question because until this question I had always assumed you just didn't bother with separator-style regexes and just repeated fragments.  I still kind of like writing `A(BA)*` or `(AB)*A` for As separated by Bs but it is nice to know some tricks when the A part shows too much redundancy, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up and the up-vote. I also found that out, see my comment on @dasblinkenlight answer.

Comment: Also, it would be correct to write `((?=$)|,(?!$))` instead of `($|,(?!$))` since the string-terminator is already matched by the `$` at the end of regex (I know it works all the same).

Comment: dasblinkenlight's answer last night had a question mark after the `($|,(?!$)` (you can see that in previous edits) so matched strings in which ranges were not separated by commas. No biggie, though: it's now fixed (happens all the time).  Like dasblinkenlight, however, I agree that the `(?=$)` is a little less readable.  When inside the parens next to a `|` you do a double take and say "wait, what... I don't see what the lookahead expression follows... oh... uh okay now I got it." Anyway - if you think of the compiled machine, you can see it won't even help, given `$` is an anchor.

Comment: I'm aware of the `?` in dasblinkenlight's original answer, my first comment to it indeed states "your regex also matches some non-well-formatted strings". I decided to accept that answer only because he gave me the first idea to solve my problem (and he corrected his answer then). Many credits also to you!

Comment: Sure, no problem, that was the correct one to accept.  You ended up with something nice, I'll bet --combining some of these answers and adding your own deduping of cell ranges.  Looking forward to a blog post or something with your final answer. ;-)

Comment: Don't know if I'm so competent to write a blog post, anyway I'll try to do my best :)

Answer (score 1):

For any series of ranges and single cells use regex pattern

```
(?!,)(?:(?:^|,)[A-Z]+(?!0)[0-9]+(?::[A-Z]+(?!0)[0-9]+)?)+
```

or if you want to match just series of same ranges (or single cells) separated by comma, then

```
^([A-Z]+(?!0)[0-9]+(?::[A-Z]+(?!0)[0-9]+)?)(,\1)*
```

Comment: I need to match the entire string, from ^ to $.

Comment: @Teejay - So use then `^(?!,)(?:(?:^|,)[A-Z]+(?!0)[0-9]+(?::[A-Z]+(?!0)[0-9]+)?)+$`

Comment: I already a have a working solution, shown in comments to @dasblinkenlight answer. Anyway, stealing your `(?!0)` solution to number not beginning with zero :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the whole string for valid ranges in one expression, you could use this regex if you don't mind prefixing the test string with a comma (like this: ,C5:H6,J5:P6,R5:DM6,C15):

```
^(?:,[A-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*(?::[A-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*)?)*$
```

If you can't change the test string, you can use this instead:

```
^(?:(?:^|,)[A-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*(?::[A-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*)?)*$
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, and yes, I was looking for the last one. Actually I tried it on http://www.cookcomputing.com/regex passing the test string and it gives me 0 matches.

Comment: @Teejay - I just tried it on the site you mentioned and it worked fine. Don't forget to prefix your test string with a comma.

Comment: Get it. But I don't want to do that. As I said, I want to do the check entirely via RegEx, just don't want to use the code. So no way to check if string is prefixed by a comma.

Comment: @Teejay - The second regex may be of use then.

Comment: RayToal and dasblinkenlight already suggested a regex that uses lookahead assertion.

Comment: @Teejay - Actually there are no lookahead or lookbehinds in my last regex. But if you have a working solution already that's good.

Comment: In fact, I asserted that RayToal and dasblinkenlight have suggested one, not that you did it :) :)